# How can I change icon of an Java native built .msi on Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, windows-installer

I am trying to build a Java project package as msi on Netbeans 8.2 following guidelines [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html). I am using Inno Setup 5.5 and Wix 3.10 to build the msi, however, I can't change the default Java icon shown on desktop for the application after setup.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Is it a shortcut on the Desktop?

Comment: yes  Lóránt Viktor Gerber

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I'd fix it by making a `Batch` file:

```
javaw -jar YourJar.jar
```

And making an `Executable` out of it with [this program](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php). Give it the path to your Batch file, set it to `Invisible appllication`. Working directory should be `Cuurent directory`. Architecture is `32-bit` and do not delete temp files on exit. In the `Version Information` tab, select your icon to be used. Click on `Compile`. Add this file to your installer, make sure to put it next to your `JAR` file. Create a shortcut to this `EXE`.